# With derby/jpa/tomcat, the database is always already booted

Tags: java, tomcat, jpa, netbeans, derby

I'm trying to use jpa with tomcat, with Derby. But I get this message : *Caused by: ERROR XSDB6: Another instance of Derby may have already booted the database*.

My persistence.xml is something like that :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="contribs" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:derby:~/contribs;create=true"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="sa"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="sa"/>
      <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="create-tables"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

I use a *ServletContextListener*, annotated with *@WebListener()*.

On *contextInitialized* I get a *EntityManagerFactory* and an *EntityManager*, and I close all on *contextDestroyed*.

I see with log tomcat call twice my ServletContextListener (I don't understand why), and the second time I get the error message.

Also I use Netbeans.

How can I resolve that ? Thanks.

Comment: Do you have many Host in your server.xml ? Or many Context mapped onto the same web application ?

Comment: I hope no :-) In my server.xml there is only one Host, and I see no Context. But it's on Netbeans stuff.

Comment: I don't know NetBeans, but check how tomcat is configured in your netbeans plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Are you hot-redeploying your application into Tomcat? Tomcat appears to frequently keep multiple copies of the web-app running, in separate application class loaders, and only one copy of your web-app is able to open Derby at a time.

One possibility is to switch from the Embedded version of Derby to the Client-Server version.

Another possibility is to restart Tomcat when the problem occurs.

Comment: Thanks. Where is this _hot deploy_ thing ? I've see the _Deploy on save_ is it that ? (if it is that, that does'nt solve my problem) I'm using a maven web application project.